# Why are twofish or other algorithms not NIST approved, are they still safe?

Tags: block-cipher, provable-security, nist

NIST has a total of 3 approved block ciphers on [their website](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/block_ciphers.html): **AES**, **TDES** and **skipjack**.

I get why those are on there (though personally I find **TDES** a bit iffy) but from my understanding **Twofish** and **Serpent** are also good enough to make the list. so why aren't they there? are they too weak? have they been broken to an extend where they are no longer safe to use?

**EXTRA:**

I'm really interested in knowing why some ciphers are recommended and others aren't. I'm looking for an algorithm to use my self, to do this I want to make a selection of a few algorithms which are safe to use so I have a reason to fall back on when i'm asked why i chose for that specific cipher other than the standard excuse because it's **AES** (or **NIST** approved)

Are there credible sources I could quote for other algorithms (such as Twofish) which shows they are still reliable?

Comment: NIST simply chose a single candidate (rijndael) to become AES. This was about standardizing one secure choice, not about allowing all secure choices. 3DES and skipjack are only there for legacy support.

Comment: If you choose Serpent or Twofish in a production application and it fails, you can be sure that you *will* be blamed for not choosing the standard, no matter which sources you bring up to back your choice.

Comment: I will not be the only to be responsible for this, the technical director and the R&D manager will both decide what algorithm we'll use, i will give recommendations based on the research I've done and they will be given my research. And we will probably go for AES. but even when we chose AES we should need some arguments why we did not chose the others.

Comment: Now that AES has been around for over 15 years, Rijndael has had **much** more analysis done on it than the other AES candidates. At this point, other candidates probably should not be used without extremely compelling reasons not to use AES.

Comment: I agree cpast, i still need to be thorough and i estimate the chances of us not using AES are negligible unless i unearth some algorithm which is much much faster than aes, but i only know one of the finalists was faster than AES but with a small margin, so like i said, negligible but still need to be thorough

Comment: @cpast: Like that AES is already broken in the academically sense? :P

Comment: @Nova That is *not* a good reason, as the attack is not only impractical but also doesn't affect AES as it's actually used. Further, AES has much more analysis on it, so the fact that no attacks actually work in practice means more than the lack of results against the others.

Comment: @cpast: It's a reason to look for other algorithms than AES in advance. Attacks only get better, and breaking AES would also destroy the security of old data. If you want to securily store data for 30 years, AES may not be what you want to use - regardless of more analysis. It's all a matter of needed security.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason NIST chose one algorithm out of the five AES finalists, even though all of them were pretty well-respected (and some were, at the time, considered likely to be more secure then Rijndael) is because NIST is a standards body, and the whole point of the AES project was to find a standard algorithm. The issue with approving lots of algorithms is that you can easily end up with multiple standards-compliant implementations that can't talk to each other because they don't implement the same algorithm. AES is supported *everywhere*, and is reasonably fast on all platforms (plus, the fact that it's so common makes stuff like AES-NI practical).

These days, it seems to be common to have several algorithms in order to provide a fallback if a flaw is found in one (for instance, that's the point of SHA-3), but that's not the normal way standards agencies work, and even with SHA-3 NIST picked *one* algorithm. It's not thought of as "good enough to make the list;" the rule is "**the** algorithm that best meets our goals for this standard."

As for why Rijndael was chosen -- it was a good balance of security, software performance, hardware performance, and ease of implementation (or so it was thought at the time; it's actually kinda tricky to securely implement). Twofish and Serpent were believed more secure at the time, but other things like performance meant they weren't good for all uses. Since the point was creating one standard, they weren't chosen.

Comment: I know how AES came to be but since twofish and serpent are also good why are they not mentioned on the site but TDES and skipjack are? I kind of get TDES even though it's at the end of it's life. but skipjack? just because the NSA created it it's there? it seems dubious, if skipjack's there serpent and twofish could be as well. but they are still secure right?

Comment: @Vincent Because that's incompatible with the purpose of a standard. NIST does not have a list of approved *algorithms*, as such; they have approved *standards*, each of which was developed in a separate process (note that they don't list Rijndael, they list AES). They are not in the business of listing things that are "good enough;" that's actually the exact opposite of their job, which is to find *one* thing that people can all use (Skipjack and DES predated AES, and Skipjack and TDES are still believed secure, so those preexisting standards haven't been *withdrawn* yet).

Comment: The better question is why they *should* list Twofish and Serpent. Why should a standards body list multiple things that are all equally acceptable alternatives to the standard? Their primary job is to find standards, not to find good cryptographic algorithms.

Comment: yes oke but than why is skipjack there all fine and dandy if they select standards but skipjack has never had the scruteny DES or AES have. for as far as i can tell it's only on there because of the NSA. if they include skipjack they might as well include verything right? or just don't include skipjack on a page for official standards. i QUOTE: "NIST recommends not to use Skipjack after 2010." from http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-131A/sp800-131A.pdf

So should i now put on my tinfoil hat?

Comment: @Vincent Skipjack was standardized in FIPS 185, back in 1994. It provides 80-bit security; this is just now becoming weak against brute-force (and in fact, NIST is about to withdraw FIPS 185). Since it's in a FIPS, it's on the list. In contrast, Twofish and Serpent didn't fill some role AES didn't fill; as the point of standards is to reduce choices, they weren't put in an official standard. Since they aren't in a FIPS, they aren't on the list of "stuff in a FIPS."

Answer (score 2):

Twofish and Serpent do not have any published non theoretical successful attacks (resulting in a complete break) so at this point in time they are considered secure.
AES was chosen because the people making the decisions at NIST felt it made the best decisions (as far as the Rijndael spec goes) of making trade offs between security, speed, computing resources (memory and CPU), and ease of implementation.
This question may be a good starting point

[How exactly was the finalist chosen in the NIST AES competition?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/11104/how-exactly-was-the-finalist-chosen-in-the-nist-aes-competition)